# How to create a persistent USB with elementary OS?

Tags: usb-drive

I simply can't create a persistent USB thumb of elementary OS (last version download from the site) using usb-creator from the repos. Is there something wrong with that package? Or it simply does not work with elementary OS?

What is the working alternative?

Comment: do you want to install elementary OS on usb?

Comment: what is your current OS and which usb creator you used?...it sounds like Ubuntu,correct?

Comment: Sorry, I am currently on eOS Freya.

Comment: Just wondering, how did you go with this? I used unetbootin on my Mac, but it seemed to duplicate the MBR (boot USB on a Mac then shows 3 options: Mac, Windows and EFI Boot). Anyway, I was able to edit syslinux.cfg to be persistent using the above info and it worked ok. I even removed the boot menu completely. But I could only have a 4GB persistent drive, I want to use the full 32gb USB stick.

Comment: Hi Craig, right now there is no easy solution for expanding to all the size of the USB stick. The only working solution uses mkusb, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397481/how-to-make-a-persistent-live-ubuntu-usb-with-more-than-4gb).

Comment: Excellent, `mkusb` worked a treat, now I have full use of my USB drive.  Just trying to locate grub.cfg to edit the menu, I can't for the life of me find it.  Its usually in /boot/grub but that grub.cfg has no effect on the boot screen.  Any ideas?

Comment: Craig, could you please write as a complete answer so that I can accept as the valid updated one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that usb-creator and unetbootin from Ubuntu 14.04 repos does not play well with UEFI.

The solution is to mount the drive after the process is complete, edit the boot.cfg file under /boot and add `persistent` to the relevant boot entry at the line:

```
linux   /casper/vmlinuz  persistent file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install Unetbootin from the official repositories.

```
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

or you could try the command `dd` which is installed by default (but should be used with extreme coution!)

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not solve the problem. The system is created, but it is not persistent. Similar to what happens when usb-creator is used.

Comment: I have the same thing happening on some of my USB sticks. Have you tried another USB stick?

Comment: I actually found a solution, and will post in here in a minute.